# Is there a way to check if a variable in Spark is parallelizable?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

So I am using `groupByKey` function in spark, but its not being parallelized, as I can see that during its execution, only 1 core is being used. It seems that the data I'm working with doesn't allow parallelization. Is there a way in spark to know if the input data is amicable to parallelization or if it's not a proper RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit of parallelization in Spark is the 'partition'. That is, RDDs are split in partitions and transformations are applied to each partition in parallel.  How RDD data is distributed across partitions is determined by the Partitioner. By default, the HashPartitioner is used which should work fine for most purposes.

You can check how many partitions your RDD is split into using:

```
rdd.partitions // Array of partitions
```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between an RDD and a pipelinedRDD, because when I try to call the partitions method, I get the error that pipelinedRDD doesnt' have a partitions function.

Comment: Looks like the Python API does not have a `rdd.partitions` method. Try `rdd.getNumPartitions` to get the nr of partitions.